# Mongoose version npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: node.js, npm, mongoose, npm-install

I'm installing `npm install mongoose-auto-increment`, but then my terminal shows up the error below. What should I do for this?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: node-mongo-registration-login-api@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: mongoose@5.13.19
npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
npm ERR!   mongoose@"^5.9.21" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer mongoose@"^4.1.12" from mongoose-auto-increment@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose-auto-increment
npm ERR!   mongoose-auto-increment@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

This my package.json file:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./server.js",
        "start:dev": "nodemon ./server.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-jwt": "^6.0.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongodb": "^3.7.4",
        "mongoose": "^5.9.21",
        "rootpath": "^0.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Peer Dependencies](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major).

Check the `peerDependencies` of the `mongoose-auto-increment@5.0.1` package.

```
$ npm view mongoose-auto-increment@5.0.1 peerDependencies
{ mongoose: '^4.1.12' }
```

This means `mongoose-auto-increment@5.0.1` package needs `mongoose` as its peer dependency and **the version must be `^4.1.12`.** And the version of the installed `mongoose` package is `"^5.9.21"`. That's why you got the warning. We have to downgrade the version of `mongoose`.

You can find all 4.x versions of `mongoose` via:

```
$ npm view mongoose@^4.1.12 version

$ npm view mongoose@^4.1.12 version
mongoose@4.1.12 '4.1.12'
mongoose@4.2.0 '4.2.0'
mongoose@4.2.1 '4.2.1'
mongoose@4.2.2 '4.2.2'
mongoose@4.2.3 '4.2.3'
mongoose@4.2.4 '4.2.4'
mongoose@4.2.5 '4.2.5'
mongoose@4.2.6 '4.2.6'
mongoose@4.2.7 '4.2.7'
mongoose@4.2.8 '4.2.8'
mongoose@4.2.9 '4.2.9'
mongoose@4.2.10 '4.2.10'
mongoose@4.3.0 '4.3.0'
mongoose@4.3.1 '4.3.1'
mongoose@4.3.2 '4.3.2'
mongoose@4.3.3 '4.3.3'
mongoose@4.3.4 '4.3.4'
mongoose@4.3.5 '4.3.5'
mongoose@4.3.6 '4.3.6'
mongoose@4.3.7 '4.3.7'
mongoose@4.4.0 '4.4.0'
mongoose@4.4.1 '4.4.1'
mongoose@4.4.2 '4.4.2'
mongoose@4.4.3 '4.4.3'
mongoose@4.4.4 '4.4.4'
mongoose@4.4.5 '4.4.5'
mongoose@4.4.6 '4.4.6'
mongoose@4.4.7 '4.4.7'
mongoose@4.4.8 '4.4.8'
mongoose@4.4.9 '4.4.9'
mongoose@4.4.10 '4.4.10'
mongoose@4.4.11 '4.4.11'
mongoose@4.4.12 '4.4.12'
mongoose@4.4.13 '4.4.13'
mongoose@4.4.14 '4.4.14'
mongoose@4.4.15 '4.4.15'
mongoose@4.4.16 '4.4.16'
mongoose@4.4.17 '4.4.17'
mongoose@4.4.18 '4.4.18'
mongoose@4.4.19 '4.4.19'
mongoose@4.4.20 '4.4.20'
mongoose@4.5.0 '4.5.0'
mongoose@4.5.1 '4.5.1'
mongoose@4.5.2 '4.5.2'
mongoose@4.5.3 '4.5.3'
mongoose@4.5.4 '4.5.4'
mongoose@4.5.5 '4.5.5'
mongoose@4.5.6 '4.5.6'
mongoose@4.5.7 '4.5.7'
mongoose@4.5.8 '4.5.8'
mongoose@4.5.9 '4.5.9'
mongoose@4.5.10 '4.5.10'
mongoose@4.6.0 '4.6.0'
mongoose@4.6.1 '4.6.1'
mongoose@4.6.2 '4.6.2'
mongoose@4.6.3 '4.6.3'
mongoose@4.6.4 '4.6.4'
mongoose@4.6.5 '4.6.5'
mongoose@4.6.6 '4.6.6'
mongoose@4.6.7 '4.6.7'
mongoose@4.6.8 '4.6.8'
mongoose@4.7.0 '4.7.0'
mongoose@4.7.1 '4.7.1'
mongoose@4.7.2 '4.7.2'
mongoose@4.7.3 '4.7.3'
mongoose@4.7.4 '4.7.4'
mongoose@4.7.5 '4.7.5'
mongoose@4.7.6 '4.7.6'
mongoose@4.7.7 '4.7.7'
mongoose@4.7.8 '4.7.8'
mongoose@4.7.9 '4.7.9'
mongoose@4.8.0 '4.8.0'
mongoose@4.8.1 '4.8.1'
mongoose@4.8.2 '4.8.2'
mongoose@4.8.3 '4.8.3'
mongoose@4.8.4 '4.8.4'
mongoose@4.8.5 '4.8.5'
mongoose@4.8.6 '4.8.6'
mongoose@4.8.7 '4.8.7'
mongoose@4.9.0 '4.9.0'
mongoose@4.9.1 '4.9.1'
mongoose@4.9.2 '4.9.2'
mongoose@4.9.3 '4.9.3'
mongoose@4.9.4 '4.9.4'
mongoose@4.9.5 '4.9.5'
mongoose@4.9.6 '4.9.6'
mongoose@4.9.7 '4.9.7'
mongoose@4.9.8 '4.9.8'
mongoose@4.9.9 '4.9.9'
mongoose@4.9.10 '4.9.10'
mongoose@4.10.0 '4.10.0'
mongoose@4.10.1 '4.10.1'
mongoose@4.10.2 '4.10.2'
mongoose@4.10.3 '4.10.3'
mongoose@4.10.4 '4.10.4'
mongoose@4.10.5 '4.10.5'
mongoose@4.10.6 '4.10.6'
mongoose@4.10.7 '4.10.7'
mongoose@4.10.8 '4.10.8'
mongoose@4.11.0 '4.11.0'
mongoose@4.11.1 '4.11.1'
mongoose@4.11.2 '4.11.2'
mongoose@4.11.3 '4.11.3'
mongoose@4.11.4 '4.11.4'
mongoose@4.11.5 '4.11.5'
mongoose@4.11.6 '4.11.6'
mongoose@4.11.7 '4.11.7'
mongoose@4.11.8 '4.11.8'
mongoose@4.11.9 '4.11.9'
mongoose@4.11.10 '4.11.10'
mongoose@4.11.11 '4.11.11'
mongoose@4.11.12 '4.11.12'
mongoose@4.11.13 '4.11.13'
mongoose@4.11.14 '4.11.14'
mongoose@4.12.0 '4.12.0'
mongoose@4.12.1 '4.12.1'
mongoose@4.12.2 '4.12.2'
mongoose@4.12.3 '4.12.3'
mongoose@4.12.4 '4.12.4'
mongoose@4.12.5 '4.12.5'
mongoose@4.12.6 '4.12.6'
mongoose@4.13.0 '4.13.0'
mongoose@4.13.1 '4.13.1'
mongoose@4.13.2 '4.13.2'
mongoose@4.13.3 '4.13.3'
mongoose@4.13.4 '4.13.4'
mongoose@4.13.5 '4.13.5'
mongoose@4.13.6 '4.13.6'
mongoose@4.13.7 '4.13.7'
mongoose@4.13.8 '4.13.8'
mongoose@4.13.9 '4.13.9'
mongoose@4.13.10 '4.13.10'
mongoose@4.13.11 '4.13.11'
mongoose@4.13.12 '4.13.12'
mongoose@4.13.13 '4.13.13'
mongoose@4.13.14 '4.13.14'
mongoose@4.13.15 '4.13.15'
mongoose@4.13.16 '4.13.16'
mongoose@4.13.17 '4.13.17'
mongoose@4.13.18 '4.13.18'
mongoose@4.13.19 '4.13.19'
mongoose@4.13.20 '4.13.20'
mongoose@4.13.21 '4.13.21'
```

Remove the `mongoose` package:

```
$ npm rm mongoose -S
```

Install the last compatible version `mongoose@^4.13.21`:

```
$ npm i mongoose@^4.13.21 -S
(#########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠋ idealTree:mquery: timing idealTree:node_modules/mquery Completed in 2ms
(#########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠋ idealTree:mquery: timing idealTree:node_modules/mquery Completed in 2ms
(#########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠋ idealTree:mquery: timing idealTree:node_modules/mquery Completed in 2ms
added 29 packages, and audited 49 packages in 1m

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

9 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 1 high, 4 critical)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

The warning is gone.

Note:

- Be careful to retry the `npm install <package>` command with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps`, it will cause potentially broken.
- The `mongoose-auto-increment` package is outdated and lacks maintenance, even the GitHub repo is gone. Be careful to use it.